# Call Javascript Method if Form is Valid in MVC4 Razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have an MVC4 Razor page and jQuery validation methods on it. I want to show a Loading spinner and I can show it when pressing Submit Button. However, if the form is not valid the spinner does not work due to not checking the validity of the form properly.

To achieve this I think 2 different approach can be used:

**Scenario I:** After user presses Submit button, the Spinner method is called. If the form is valid, the Spinner will be shown and the form will be submitted. If not, the spinner will not be shown and the form will not be submitted. After the user validate the form and presses the Submit button, it will work as the first stage.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#submitbtn").click(function () {
        if ($('#myform').valid()) { //If there is no validation error
            //Show "Loading..." spinner 
            $("#loading").fadeIn();
            var opts = {
                lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
                length: 7, // The length of each line
                width: 4, // The line thickness
                radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
                color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
                speed: 1, // Rounds per second
                trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
                hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            };
            var target = document.getElementById('loading');
            var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
        }
    });
});
```

```
<input id="submitbtn" type="submit" value="Send" />
```

**Scenario II:** The Form will be validated with jQuery validation method as the other controls. In that case, if the Form is valid, showSpinner() method will be called. If not, the Form will not be submitted and the showSpinner() will not be called. Here is the method like above just a little changes and jQuery validation method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSpinner() {
        //if ($('#myform').valid()) { //As the Form is checked already, there is no need to check again.

            //Show "Loading..." spinner if all the components on the Form are valid
            $("#loading").fadeIn();
            var opts = {
                lines: 12, // The number of lines to draw
                length: 7, // The length of each line
                width: 4, // The line thickness
                radius: 10, // The radius of the inner circle
                color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb
                speed: 1, // Rounds per second
                trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
                shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
                hwaccel: false // Whether to use hardware acceleration
            };
            var target = document.getElementById('loading');
            var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
        //}
    }
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
jQuery(function () {
    //...
    jQuery("#myform").validate({
        expression: "if (VAL) {showSpinner(); return true;} else {return false;}",
        message: "Form is not valid!.."
    });
});
/* ]]> */
```

How can I apply this properly by using one of this approach?

Comment: Why are you binding to a button? Bind to the `submit` event (not everyone presses a button). And although *most* browsers execute a click on `[type="submit"]`, not all of them do.

Comment: Could you clarify a little bit more with an example? Because I have not used that approach before.

Comment: Instead of `$('#submitBtn').click()` you should bind to `$('#myForm').submit()`

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it does not make any sense. I think the problem is related to JQuery. Because I have tried lots of methods containing jQuery pages, but lots of the errors I have encountered are caused from jQuery valid() and validate() methods. I use different versions of jquery-1.x.x.js files and all the needed validation javascripts. So, is not there anyone else having used such a kind of Form Validation ever before?